# Why the batch normalization is not applied on the last layer of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, batch-normalization

As I found in some tutorials, they didn't perform BN on last layer. It seems like a best practice, but I didn't find any detailed explanation of why this helps training.

Can anyone kindly help me brief the reason for why doing this?

Answer (score 2):

On a final layer you don’t want to make any transformations beyond those needed to transform your outputs to appropriate form, i.e. change shape, for classification scale to unit range, or -1 to +1, for regression not use any activation, or use something as ReLU, or exponential function if the outputs need to be non-negative etc.